# How to open a popup and send a JSON object to it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to send a [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) object to a [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) file while my script opens that PHP file in a new **popup** window. Is it possible to send it via POST method (by jQuery or without it)?

If not, how do I convert JSON to a [URL encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) string? Is there any JavaScript function?

Comment: what do you want to send from where.. your question is not clear

Comment: the json object is ready and i want to send it to another domain (popup) when user clicks on a button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may create a form (on the fly) with an input (where you fill the value with the JSON) and a target-attribute regarding to name of the popup (second parameter of `window.open()`).

Then send this form.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open the popup: `var popup = window.open(...)`
2. Assign the json object to a new variable in the new window: `popup.json = ...`
3. Use the variable `json` in your popup (it will be accessible as `window.json` or just `json` from JavaScript code running in the popup).

Comment: This variable wouldn't be accessible via PHP/POST

Comment: no JavaScript variable is accessible from PHP, so I don't see your point. He has to access it, put it into an AJAX request and POST it to the PHP code like any other variable. My example just shows how you can copy data from one browser window to another.

Comment: Thats the point, he will need to send the data the usual way, without AJAX(also see his comment, the target will be under a different domain where you cannot set anything via JS), using a form(there is no other way sending POST-data)

Answer (score 1):

There's a [JSON encoder/decoder](http://devpro.it/JSON/files/JSON-js.html) that looks like it would do the job. You could call this to encode your object before adding it to your querystring.

**Example**

```
alert(JSON.encode([0,1,false,true,null,[2,3],{"some":"value"}]));
// [0,1,false,true,null,[2,3],{"some":"value"}]

alert(JSON.decode('[0,1,false,true,null,[2,3],{"some":"value"}]'))
// 0,1,false,true,,2,3,[object Object]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Ajax API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax) to do so... In the Ajax [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface), you can specify the data property and set it a [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), and it will send the data to the server based on the type you have set, that is, [GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) or [POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29).

For example:

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: url,                     // Your post URL
    type:"POST",                  // or GET
    data: {a:1}                   // In your case, your JSON object
    success:function(response){}, // Function that will be called when your posted URL responds
    crossDomain: true,            // If it's a cross-domain request
    dataType: "json"              // Response datatype: JSON, text, HTML, XML, etc.
}
);
```

One thing to note is that if your response needs to be processed, you need to get around the same origin policy set by the browser. Please read about the same. You could use something called [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). It's part of the Ajax API.

I hope this is what you want.

Comment: This does not open the URL in a popup, as the OP requested.