# post json to new window php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I want to post json output to a new window. How could I achieve this? Thank You!

**Here is my code:**

```
 function onSuccess(data, status)
    {
        data = $.trim(data);
        $("#notification").text(data);
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submit").click(function(){
            var formData = $("#callAjaxForm").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "callajax.php",
                cache: false,
                data: formData,
                success: onSuccess,
                error: onError
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
        <form id="callAjaxForm">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" value=""  />

                <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" value=""  />
                <button data-theme="b" id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

and below is callajax.php (I want to show the json information on this page)

```
<?php
$fName = $_POST['firstName'];
$lName = $_POST['lastName'];
echo("First Name: " . $firstName . " Last Name: " . $lastName);
?>
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187691/how-to-open-a-popup-and-send-a-json-object-to-it

Comment: Yes I did, but when he opens a new page where the information will not be displayed

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make a JSON representation of the data you are sending from the form use:

```
<?php
$fName = $_POST['firstName'];
$lName = $_POST['lastName'];
$resp = array('first_name'=>$fName,'last_name'=>$lName);
echo json_encode($resp);
?>
```

Comment: @user3354891 I changed the answer hope you understand it now .

Comment: That is a valid JSON but not the one you are looking for LOL, there was an error in the variables names of my answer i edited it and it should work now. Sorry